# meaning of "strongly typed view"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What is the meaning of "strongly typed view" in ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: What trouble have you had in searching for this term on the Internet and trying to determine what it means? What, specifically, confuses you? What have you done to try and resolve your question by yourself?

Comment: @Noon, SO is the internet. I did a search on the internet and found this question. If SO serves to answer very simple questions, I don't see this as a bad thing. It's not like SO is going to run out of pages or something.

Comment: @MrBoJangles: Your reply makes no sense; at the time of asking this question this question obviously didn't exist for it to be found, so my comment is appropriate. Feel free to sit around answering all questions that are askable for the purpose of turning this into a duplicated source of everything, though. I won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type you return from the controller should match the type of your view.

e.g if your view `Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyModel>"` then your controller should return MyModel

Comment: Or, in razor syntax, `@model Your.Model.Here`